# Preventing application from receiving a keystroke

Tags: cocoa, screenshot, keystroke

I want to create an application in which, when it starts executing, the user can not perform keystrokes and the application cannot receive any events from keyboard, such as command+Q,command+shift+3, etc.
I just want to disable some key combination so that i can make my application secure

Comment: What do you mean can not? You can't overcome operating system which serves your application through your application! If you are looking for a way to disable CMD+Q form quitting your application, Its another story

Comment: possible duplicate of [code in cocoa how to prevent screen shot.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307465/code-in-cocoa-how-to-prevent-screen-shot)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question you asked yesterday which appears to be an exact duplicate of a question another user who worded it nearly identically;  small world or multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a carbon evemt for this hot key (3+shift+cmd)
http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/03/global-keyboard-shortcuts-with-carbon.html